# How to hide multiple columns at once in Excel 2007 using vba

Tags: excel, hide, vba

I would like to hide multiple columns inside an excel worksheet. This works pretty fine using:

ActiveSheet.Range("R10:CO10").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

"R10" is the first and fix column to hide. The second column and all columns between to hide will be dynamically determined depending on it´s date value.

Sample Coding:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim start As String
    Dim ende As String
    start = "R10"
    ende = "CO10"
    Dim d As Date
    d = Date
    For Each c In Range("R10:HU10")
        If c = (d - 8) Then
            ende = **how to assign???**
        End If
        If c = (d - 7) Then
            Application.Goto c, True
        End If
    Next c
    'ActiveSheet.Range(**"start:ende"**).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End Sub
```

Row 10 holds date values and I would like to hide all columns which dates are older than 7 days and I can´t find any hints about hiding multiple columns using variables or with column identifier or the number of the column etc.

The use of variables ends up in runtime error 1004.

Comment: just hide as you go through the loop: `c.EntireColumn.Hidden = c < (d-7)`  in place of your whole if statements.

Comment: easy to implement and it works fine but the screen is flickering while hide each column sequentially. That is the reason why I want to hide a range of columns at once

Comment: Then turn off screen updating. `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at the beginning of the sub and `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` at the end.

Comment: thank you Scott - easy workaround and the result counts. Would be nice to see how it works with variables that holds the range values but your solution is perfect for my needs...

Comment: Look into UNION(), You can cycle through your column and if it is less then 7 days then add the cell to the Union()  then at the end you can hide the whole range columns created by the union.  Or look into Cells() and save the column number of the one that is = 8 days and use that column number in Cells to set the end range.

Comment: ok - new stuff but maybe VBA and I are not compatible ;-) Seems to be that nobody has ever tried to hide multiple columns at once. Union and Cells are interesting and I understand the concept behind but I do not have an idea how to use it to hide more than one column at once.`ActiveSheet.Range("start:ende").EntireColumn.Hidden = True` How to replace start resp. ende with a union expression

Answer (score 0):

As Scott pointed out, my first answer was not complete. You can use the following function:

```
Function GetColChars(col As Integer) As String

    Dim coldown As Integer 'Column Countdown
    Dim colrem As Integer 'Coumn Value Remaining
    Dim colname As String 'Temporary String value for column name

    Const alphanums = 26
    Const aposition = 64
    coldown = col
    colname = ""

    While coldown > 0

        colrem = coldown Mod alphanums
        If colrem = 0 Then colrem = 26
        newchar = Chr(64 + colrem)
        colname = newchar & colname
        coldown = Int((coldown - 1) / alphanums)

    Wend

    GetColChars = colname

 End Function
```

Then call the function to get the column letters:

```
ende = GetColChars(c.column)
```

Comment: Hello, I will give your solution a try tomorrow. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested Scotts solution approach and finally got it working. In that case that some other people will struggle with the same problems, getting a working solution, here is my solution:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

Dim lastDateRangeColumn As Range
Dim givenDateRange As Range 
Set givenDateRange = ActiveSheet.Range("R10:HU10")
Dim firstDateRangeColumn As Range 
Set firstDateRangeColumn = ActiveSheet.Range("R10")

Dim todaysDate As Date: todaysDate = Date

For Each tempDateRangeColumn In givenDateRange
    If tempDateRangeColumn < (todaysDate - 7) Then
        Set lastDateRangeColumn = ActiveSheet.Range(tempDateRangeColumn.Address)
    End If
    If tempDateRangeColumn = (todaysDate - 7) Then
        Application.Goto tempDateRangeColumn, True
    End If
Next tempDateRangeColumn

Dim firstColumnNumber As Long  
Dim lastColumnNumber  As Long
firstColumnNumber = Range(firstDateRangeColumn.Address).Column  
lastColumnNumber  = Range(lastDateRangeColumn.Address).Column

Dim rangeToBeHidden   As Range 
Set rangeToBeHidden = Range(Cells(1, firstColumnNumber), Cells(1, lastColumnNumber))

rangeToBeHidden.EntireColumn.Hidden = True

End Sub
```